# Funcionamiento extraño modulo wifi SAMW25

Tags: c, arduino, atmel

Buenos días! me encuentro trabajando con la placa **samw25 xplained pro** de Atmel y por supuesto con su Atmel Studio...

Estoy probando la mayoría de sus proyectos, y van muy bien, pero tengo un problema cuando pruebo las conexiones TCP.

Al instalarle el programa de TCP Client o Server, indiferente cual de ellos, siempre se queda en este punto:

> wifi_cb: M2M_WIFI_RESP_CON_STATE_CHANGED: DISCONNECTED

¿A que se debe este motivo? como digo es un ejemplo suministrado por Atmel, por lo que debería funcionar tal y como se ve en el [manual](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-42437-software-programming-guide-for-sam-w25-xplained-pro_userguide.pdf), pero no es así...

Agradezco toda la ayuda posible! un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

El "punto" donde se te queda el programa es una interrupción que ocurre cuando el access point está configurado incorrectamente o cuando vos llamas a la función disconnect from AP.

Si estás usando un ejemplo de Atmel tenés que cambiarle el nombre al AP, password y tipo de seguridad ya que por default trae una configuración de una red que logicamente estará fuera de tu rango.

Espero que te sirva, cualquier problema que tengas con este modulo no dudes en preguntar que yo lo estoy usando sin problemas.

Te dejo un screenshot de los defines que tenés que modificar (los encontrarás en main.h)

[image: Configuraciones a modificar]